# Click buttons using AutomationID in AutoIT

Tags: autoit

I am automating a VB6 application using AutoIT and have hit some issues.

The application has a 'Toolboxes' window which contains an `SSTab` control with 18 tabs in 6 rows. There are over 100 instances of the `ThunderRT6CommandButton` class. My AutoIT script is supposed to interact with specific buttons, and so far I've been using `ControlClick`:

```
ControlClick($sToolboxes, '', '[CLASS:ThunderRT6CommandButton; INSTANCE:81]')
```

The issue is that when I change to a different tab and close the toolboxes window the application remembers which tab was open. This means that the next time I open the toolboxes window the tabs are initiated in a different order and all of the instance numbers of the buttons have changed.
 I can't even call `ControlClick` and specify the text of the button to be clicked because that isn't unique; about 20 of the buttons are simply labelled 'Apply'.

Using *Inspect.exe* I noticed that each button has a unique `AutomationID` which is constant even when closing and reopening the toolboxes window after shuffling the tabs around.

**Is there any way that I can click buttons using their AutomationID in AutoIT?**

The only other fix for this that I can think of is making the AutoIT script launch the application itself so that the toolboxes are in the same order each time the script runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AutoIT Window Info tool shows the `AutomationID`, but calls it "ID":

[image]

I changed my script to include `ID:##` instead of an instance number and it works:

```
ControlClick($sToolboxes, '', '[CLASS:ThunderRT6CommandButton; ID:245]')
```